# Design a counting measure of the element number in a MongoDB array property in cube.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cube.js, mongodb-connector-for-bi

I'm using [cube.js](https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js) with MongoDB through [MongoDB Connector for BI](http://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/) and [MongoBI Driver](http://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/) and so far so good. I'd like to have a cube.js numerical **measure** that counts the element length from a MongoDB array of object nested property. Something like:

```
{
  "nested": {
    "arrayPropertyName": [
      {
        "name": "Leatha Bauch",
        "email": "Leatha.Bauch76@hotmail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "Pedro Hermiston",
        "email": "Pedro76@hotmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to figure that out looking at the docs and I was wondering if that is even possible.

I tried with `type: count`:

```js
    MyNestedArrayPropertyCounter: {
      sql: `${CUBE}.\`nested.arrayPropertyName\``,
      type: `count`,
      format: `number`,
    },
```

but I'm getting

```js
Error: Error: Unknown column 'nested.arrayPropertyName' in 'field list'
```

Any help/advice is really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BI treats nested arrays as separate relational tables. See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-the-mongodb-connector-for-bi-20

That's why you get unknown column error, it's not part of the parent document table.

So my guess you have to build schema on the nested array and then build measure count with dimension on parent object id.

Hope it halps.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Michael Parshin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931381/michael-parshin) advice and here's my findings and outcomes to overcome the problem:

1. `LEFT JOIN` approach with cube.js [joins](https://cube.dev/docs/joins). I found it painfully slow and most of the time it endend out in a timeout even when querying was performed through command line SQL clients;
2. Launch [mongosqld](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/current/) with [--prejoin](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#cmdoption-mongosqld-prejoin) flag. That was a better option since `mongosqld` automatically adds master table columns/properties to the secondary tables thus enabling you to conveniently query cube.js [measures](https://cube.dev/docs/measures) without joining a secondary [Cube](https://cube.dev/docs/getting-started-cubejs-schema#1-creating-a-cube);
3. Wrote a mongo script that fetch/iterate/precalc and persist `nested.arrayPropertyName` count in a separate property of the collection documents.

### Conclusion

Leaving out option 1, **option 3** significantly outperforms option 2, typically less than a seconds against more than 20 seconds on my local machine. I compared both options with the same [measure](https://cube.dev/docs/measures), different [timeDimension](https://cube.dev/docs/query-format#time-dimensions-format) ranges and granularity.

Most probably I'll incorporate array count precalculation into mongo document back-end persisting logic.